aws codecommit set up
i am get this type error how to solve
Cloning into 'repositorytest'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repositorytest/': The requested URL returned error: 403am
First of all, I created a user in AWS IAM with the AWSCodeCommitFullAccess permission attached. I also created credentials (an access key ID and secret access key) for this user. After that, I created a Code Commit repository and copied the HTTPS clone URL to set it up in my code editor. However, I encountered an error.

Did you aws configure from CLI?

Can you creating an iam user (not accesskey/secret), upload a ssh key and the git clone? This is the classic way for git

Please provide more details about the error message and the steps you followed. Did you configure the AWS CLI with your credentials?
